# Will I always get the keys in the same order when I call ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config, configurationmanager, appsettings

For `web.config` and `app.config`, when I call `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys`, do I get the keys in the same order they appear in the config file all the time?

I couldn't find any mention of that on MSDN.

Comment: Most probably, but I don't think it is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is of type `NameValueCollection` and their order is undetermined. `AllKeys` returns string array based on the `NameValueCollection`, thus its order will also be undetermined.

See: [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Collections of this type do not preserve the ordering of element, and
>   no particular ordering is guaranteed when enumerating the collection.

If you want a definite order the use

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.OrderBy(r=> r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would it matter? It's a keyed collection: if order is important to you, put it in the order you want it. You should also bear in mind that the data in `<appsettings>` comes from multiple sources. It is retrieved from some subset of

- machine configuration (`machine.config`)
- application configuration (`app.config`)
- user-specific configuration
- IIS application host configuration
- root `web.config`
- any of a number of `web.config` files in the application path in IIS.

Further, `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is a `NameValueCollection`. I suspect—but don't know for sure—that its backing store is a hash table. In so, the ordering you'll see is related to

- the computed hash value of the keys,
- the hash bucket to which those keys are assigned, and
- insertion order (actually, order of operations — insertion and deletion, since deletion might leave an empty slot in the hash bucket that gets filled by a subsequent insertion).

The same set of keys, inserted in different sequences, would display different orderings on retrieval.